# find maximum sum of xors

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, subset-sum, bit-manipulation, xor

we are given an Array

Array size <= 10^4 .

0 <= A[i] <= 15

We need to partition the array into 4 subsets (each subset can have zero or more elements ). Take xor of each subset and sum those xors.

for example,  one subset could have indices 0, 3, and 7, and another subset could have indices 1, 2, and 4
find the max sum.

4^n approach is very expensive.

there are only 16 different values of xor so for each value of xor=X we can search in array if is it possible to partition the array such that we get xor=X.

Comment: Have you tried dynamic programming?

Comment: Does each part have to be from a contiguous/consecutive part of the array?  You might find https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info helpful.

Comment: Hint: with n array elements this is very easy to do in O(n).

Comment: @D.W. No. We need to divide the array into 4 subsets. each subset can have zero or more elements.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus can you elaborate?

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify.  So one subset could have indices 0, 3, and 7, and another subset could have indices 1, 2, and 4, for instance?  I still don't see this specified in the question.  If you ran across this problem somewhere, can you edit the question to credit the original source where you encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

For every $i \in \{0,\ldots,n\}$ (where $n$ is the length of the array) and for every $a,b,c \in \{0,\ldots,15\}$, we determine whether it is possible to partition the first $i$ elements of the array into four subsets, the first three of which XOR to $a,b,c$, respectively. We also compute the XOR of the entire array. Using the information for $i = n$, we can determine the possible XORs resulting from partitions of the array into four subsets, and so calculate the maximum sum. The resulting algorithm runs in linear time.

Comment: I think there should be an alternative algorithm if the elements are allowed to be large.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Can you give a small example?

Comment: It's best if you programmed it on your own.

Comment: … that way you learn, and Yuval has time to answer more questions.